# Tangent bundle is orientable

Tags: geometry, manifolds

I am having some trouble finishing a proof that the tangent bundle of any manifold is orientable.

What I've done so far is calculate the transition function between two standard charts on the bundle. i.e.

$\bar{\phi} \bar{\psi^{-1}} : (x^1,...,x^n,v^1,...,v^n)\mapsto(y^1,...,y^n,v^{i}\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^i},...,v^{i}\frac{\partial y^n}{\partial x^i})$.

Now I want the differential(push-forward) matrix of this map. This breaks up naturally into 4 blocks. Where the first and last are the differentials for 
$\phi\psi^{-1}$, but I am stuck calculating the other two blocks. i.e. what is
$\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial v^i}$ or 
$\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^1}\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^i}$?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, I am not asking for the general method of solving this question, I'm just stuck on a technical detail.

Comment: Did you see the answer on the other topic? The positivity is what you're going after.

Comment: Yer, I want to show the determinant is positive. But I am unsure about the partials I mentioned above. I think they are zero, but I don't know why.

Comment: Just to make the point that the tangent bundle is always orientable as a manifold, but not as a bundle ,e.g,  you need to be able to reduce the structure group.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate this part of the matrix. Since you have an upper left block all of zeros, the determinant will be the product of the determinants of the "main diagonal blocks".